# A simplest recursive function returns undefined

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
function forLoop(x) {
    if (x >= 10) {
       console.log(x); // here if I add console.log(x) , x value is 10
        return (x); // next line if i return x output = undefined
    }
    forLoop(x + 1);
}

console.log(forLoop(0));
```

The output is "undefined" instead of 10.

Can anyone explain how recursion works in detail and how to fix the bug in my code?

Comment: You just missed to return: `return forLoop(x + 1)`

Comment: Here is a link to recursive function - http://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/

Comment: thank you for your reply but if u write return forLoop(x+1); in forLoop function control will go back to console.log(forLoop(0)); again and again but what I want is, I need to call that function only once and within that function it will call multiple times and finally when if condition satisfied it should return me a result. but the above code will return every time when the if condition fails, correct me if i go wrong as I am a newbie

Answer (score 2):

If x is greater or equal to 10, the function returns x.

Otherwise, it calls itself **but returns nothing**.

You have to return something when the `if` fails.

```
function forLoop(x) {
    if (x >= 10) {
        return (x);
    }
    return forLoop(x + 1);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but if u write return forLoop(x+1); in forLoop function control will go back to console.log(forLoop(0)); and

Comment: The entire point of recursion is that a function calls itself multiple times.

Comment: thank you for your reply but if u write return forLoop(x+1); in forLoop function control will go back to console.log(forLoop(0)); again and again but what I want is, I need to call that function only once and within that function it will call multiple times and finally when if condition satisfied it should return me a result. but the above code will return every time when the if condition fails, correct me if i go wrong as I am a newbie

Comment: "if u write return forLoop(x+1); in forLoop function control will go back to console.log(forLoop(0)); again and again" — No, it won't.

Comment: but the definition of return is - The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

Comment: here the function caller is console.log(forLoop(0));

Comment: @VinayK — Yes. A value, not an expression. `forLoop(x + 1)` will be evaluated and the result will be returned to whatever called the function.

Comment: Here's an idea: Instead of arguing about how this code won't work, try running it so that you can see that it does.

Comment: thank you its working fine , but I had the doubt y a return there because function forLoop(x) {
    if (x >= 10) {
        return (x);
    }
    forLoop(x + 1);
}

console.log(forLoop(0));

Comment: leave it , I will understand more about recursion , thank you for your time